# access - one form, update one table and insert to another

Tags: ms-access

I am new to the syntax of vba in access, and I have a question about the queries.

I have a form, and in the form I have for example a field called "A" which I want to insert into table `table_a` and a two other fields, one called "B_ID" which contains ID and another field called "B" which I want to update in `table_b` (where the ID is equal to field "B_ID".

any ideas how to do it in VBA for access?

in php and MySQL I would simply have two queries like so:
`INSERT INTO table_b (field_A) VALUES ($_POST['A'])`
`UPDATE table_b WHERE b_id = $_POST['B_ID'] SET B = $_POST['B']`
* or something like this...

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any VBA code if you create the form based on updateable query. Tables should be linked using column(s) with unique key in master table and query should not contain aggregate functions. There are some other limitations, but in most cases it will work for simple queries

If tables are not linked or you don't want to use then on form, use code like this:

```
Dim db As Database

Set db = CurrentDb
db.Execute "INSERT INTO table_b (field_A) SELECT " & Me.A, dbFailOnError
db.Execute "UPDATE table_b SET B=" & Me.b & " WHERE b_id = " & Me.B_ID, dbFailOnError
```

Here we suppose that you have on form fields A, B and B_ID with numeric values and corresponding columns in tables are numeric. If fields are text, add single quotes in SQL strings.

Comment: I build the form as simple as possible... I didn't make an update query for it or something, and also didn't build a relation. I am not sure I did it in the best way though,,, I thought to myself that if I would do it with VBA it will be the most cosutmizable and flexible as possible. so, any other ideas?

Comment: Hi @Sergey S. thanks for the answer, though for some reason this code duplicates every row I add in the database... any idea why?

Comment: Set a breakpoint to this code and make sure that it called once first. I believe you placed it into event, which called multiple times

Comment: Hi @Sergey S., thanks. I found the problam - for some reason, in this form and also in other forms on my program, I don't need to press on any button in order to add a row to the database, but just to change the input fields, and then close the form, and the data is added to the db. how can I do that only when you press the button it's being added? maybe it's because the way I opened my forms?

Comment: If you want to disable manual rows adding in form, change form property Data->Allow Additions to no and requery the form after adding the row using VBA

Comment: when I change it, then all the input fields are gone and I see a blank form

Comment: Use unbound controls then for entering new data and bound controls for editing/displayng

Comment: thank you @Sergey S. for your help, but I am new to ms,,, and still, even when I add a completely new control to the form I don't see it. how do I make it be unbound?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101075/discussion-between-sergey-s-and-dani-jinji).

Comment: hi guys, any idea? still stuck with it.. or should I build my forms again from scratch?